# What's the procedure to re-download locally deleted files using SFTP Inbound

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

As per this ***[doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html)*** couldn't find the right process to re-downloading a locally removed file from remote SFTP.

The requirement is, to delete local file which already been fetched from remote SFTP and use sftp-inbound-adapter ([DSL configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound)) to re-fetch that same file when required. In this implementation, `MetadataStore` haven't been persisted into any external system like *`PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore`* or *Redis Metadata Store*. So as per **[doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound)**, `MetadataStore` stored in **In-Memory**.

Couldn't find any way to remove meta data of that remote file from `MetadataStore` to re-fetch the locally deleted file using `file_name`. And don't have any clue, how should this `removeRemoteFileMetadata()` callback needs to be implemented (**[according to this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-remote-file-info)**).

Configuration class contain followings:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileFlow() {
        SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec spec = Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpConfig.getSftpSessionFactory())
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .patternFilter(Constants.FILE_NAME_CONVENTION)
                .remoteDirectory(sftpConfig.getSourceLocation())
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
                .localDirectory(new File(sftpConfig.getDestinationLocation()));

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(spec, e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter").autoStartup(false)
                        .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000).get()))
                .channel(MessageChannels.direct().get())
                .handle(message -> {
                    log.info("Fetching File : " + message.getHeaders().get("file_name").toString());
                })
                .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ChainFileListFilter`, with a `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter` and a `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

Use a `SimpleMetadataStore` to store the state in memory (or some other `MetadataStore`).

`new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store, "somePrefix");`

Then, `store.remove(key)` where `key` is `somePrefix` + `fileName`.

Use a similar filter in the `localFilter` with `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

Comment: do i need to create a `SimpleMetadataStore` bean like this ?  
`@Bean
public SimpleMetadataStore store() { return new SimpleMetadataStore(); }`

Comment: should i use absolute path of the _**remote file**_ or the _**local file**_ or just the _**file name**_ to construct the `key`?

Comment: For the sftp filter, it's the remote file name; for the file system filter it's the absolute path. See the `fileName()` method in each filter. It's called from `buildKey()` in the abstract class.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to solve this and I used [Tanvir Hossain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4882483/tanvir-hossain)'s reference code. I coded like this.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileFlow() {
    SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec spec = Sftp
            .inboundAdapter(sftpConfig.getSftpSessionFactory())
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
            .filter(sftpFileListFilter())
            .localFilter(systemFileListFilter())
            .remoteDirectory(sftpConfig.getSourceLocation())
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
            .localDirectory(new File(sftpConfig.getDestinationLocation()));

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(spec, e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter").autoStartup(false)
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000).get()))
            .channel(MessageChannels.direct().get())
            .handle(message -> {
                log.info("Fetching File : " 
                        + message.getHeaders().get("file_name").toString());
            })
            .get();
}


private FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter systemFileListFilter() {

    return new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store(), prefix);
}


private ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpFileListFilter() {

    ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> chainFileListFilter = 
                                                new ChainFileListFilter<>();
    chainFileListFilter.addFilters(
            new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store(), prefix),
            new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpConfig.getFileFilterValue())
    );
    return chainFileListFilter;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMetadataStore store() {
    return new SimpleMetadataStore();
}
```

and my `Controller` for removing metadata is like below :

```
public class Controller { 

    private final SimpleMetadataStore simpleMetadataStore;

    public Controller(SimpleMetadataStore simpleMetadataStore) {

           this.simpleMetadataStore = simpleMetadataStore;

    }

    @GetMapping("/test/remove-metadata/{type}/{fileName}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String removeFileMetadata(
             @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
             @PathVariable("type") String type
    ) {
        String prefix = definedPrefix;
        String filePath = "";
        if(type.equals("local")){
            filePath = "/local/storage/path/" + fileName;
        }else if(type.equals("remote")){
            filePath = fileName
        }
        String key = prefix + filePath;

        simpleMetadataStore.remove(key);
        return key;
    }

}
```

I am getting my desired file. It is re-fetching file for me.

Comment: Thanks, i was adding `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` filter and `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter` incorrectly. this helped a lot.

Comment: But in your controller, you used  a type to choose absolute path or just file name. Which one worked for you?

Comment: I added these for testing purpose. But the **remote** type worked for me.